# Regex for homework

Tags: java, regex

This is for some homework for my beginner class.

> An organisation has assigned all clients an identity number. The identity number is of the following format:
>
> - 2 numeric characters (digits without leading 0s), followed by 3 numeric characters (digits) and 3 numeric characters (digits) separated by a single whitespace
> - or 3 numeric characters (digits without leading 0s) followed by 3 numeric characters (digits) and 3 numeric characters (digits) separated by a single whitespace.
> - any number < 10 000 000 or >150 000 000 is invalid.

This is my attempt:

```
([\\d]{2}[\\s][\\d]{3}[\\s][\\d]{3})|([\\d]{3}[\\s][\\d]{3}[\\s][\\d]{3})
```

However the following outputs should not work but they do:

```
153 394 111
943 293 492
098 302 203
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

The following are valid inputs:

```
11 304 982
39 683 234
139 920 393
```

The following are non valid inputs:

```
153 394 111
3 394 234
89 909 98
```

Comment: Why should they not work? I can see the third one has a leading zero (and you're not checking for those at all), but what's wrong with the top two?

Comment: [Does this visualization of your regex help](https://regexper.com/#(%5B%5Cd%5D%7B2%7D%5B%5Cs%5D%5B%5Cd%5D%7B3%7D%5B%5Cs%5D%5B%5Cd%5D%7B3%7D)%7C(%5B%5Cd%5D%7B3%7D%5B%5Cs%5D%5B%5Cd%5D%7B3%7D%5B%5Cs%5D%5B%5Cd%5D%7B3%7D))?

Comment: I can't even make sense of the description. It should be much less ambiguous, and provide examples.

Comment: They shouldn't work because my homework tells me a group of outputs that should work and some that should not. These ouputs seem to work, but is included in the "should not work" group

Comment: By the way, as far as I can see, all the square brackets in your expression are redundant.

Comment: Then your problem is with whoever set the homework. Unless that person reads SO, I don't think we're going to be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Now you've given more examples, there seems to be no rationale distinguishing valid from invalid inputs at all.

Comment: @AndyTurner isn't the visualization incorrect? It says 2 times every time there is a {3}, and 1 time every time there is a {2}.

Comment: @JBNizet I presume it means "repeat this _n_ times (after the first time)"

Comment: @JBNizet I was a bit puzzled by that too; but I think that it's saying you can follow the loop edge `N-1` times to match the thing `N` times overall.

Comment: @EllenPage I don't see why `153 394 111` or `943 293 492` are invalid. They match "3 numeric characters (digits without leading 0s) followed by 3 numeric characters (digits) and 3 numeric characters (digits) separated by a single whitespace."

Comment: This looks right to me but I have no idea what makes "153 394 111" wrong.

Comment: I am sorry for wasting everybody's time. At the bottom of the homework it says "Any number < 10 000 000 or >150 000 000 is invalid". Thank you for the help nonetheless.

Comment: @EllenPage please edit that info into your question, so answers can account for that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
\b(1[0-4][1-9]|[1-9]\d) \d{3} \d{3}\b|150 000 000
```

It matches:

```
11 304 982
39 683 234
139 920 393
150 000 000
```

And excludes:

```
153 349 111
053 394 111
3 394 234
89 909 98
```

---

#### Explanation

`\b([1-9]\d|1[0-4][1-9])`: begins with a number between `10` and `149`

`\d{3}`: followed by a whitespace and 3 digits

`\d{3}\b`: again

`|150 000 000`: in order to accept the value `150 000 000`

Note that I only accept the character  , and not all whitespaces. You may want to change all   by `\s`, it depends of your needs.

## [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/24q0iU/3)

Comment: @EllenPage As the first character only accept [1-9], it will exclude `053 934 111`. Check the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/24q0iU/2) link. :)

Comment: Sorry. My mistake I meant to say this doesn't exclude "153 934 111"

Comment: @EllenPage Yes, it doesn't. But why it should? Why is `153 834 111` invald? What it the rule? From your description, I understand it differently.

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot to add a single piece of info which was located at the bottom of the homework which I didn't see at first. "Any number < 10 000 000 or >150 000 000 is invalid." I am so sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^(?:(?:1[0-4]|[1-9])\d \d{3} \d{3}|150 000 000)$` to check your identity numbers. Note that you may omit the anchors if you use it with `.matches` function and have to double backslashes in java string literals.

`(?:1[0-4]|[1-9])\d` checks for a 2-digit number that starts with 1-9 (0 is invalid) or a 3-digit number that starts with 10-14 to account for the value restriction.

Sadly only numbers greater than `150 000 000` are invalid, so `150 000 000` itself isn't - therefor the last alternation.

Another approach could be checking the overall format (e.g. `^[1-9]\d\d? \d{3} \d{3}$`), afterwards removing the spaces and doing a usual numeric check for the last restriction.